# Unable to access my PosgreSQL database via my RShiny app (macOS Monterey)

Tags: r, postgresql, ssh, shiny

I'm creating a Shinyapp. I need to read information from a PosgreSQL database hosted on my computer. I have configured PosgreSQL files postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf as explained here : https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection . On R, this code works fine:

`con<-DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),dbname = mydbname,host = myprivateIP,port = 5432, user = user, password = secret)`

`map_feature<-pgGetGeom(con, query)`  etc.

The code works locally on my computer, as on other computers with RStudio + connection,to the same router/wifi.

Tho, when I publish the code and try to make it work through its adress directely online (https://my-code.shinyapps.io/page/)the app crashes, and error message is :

`Warning: Error in : could not connect to server: No route to host. Is the server running on host "192.XXX.X.XX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

**What am I missing ? Why does it work locally but not from the code hosted online ?**

Comment: Does your `myprivateIP` address start with "192"? Those address are private to a network and cannot be seen by the shinyapps server. Your local machine would need a public IP address.

Comment: Okay. Well changing my myprivateIP with mypublicIP and it gives me the same type of error : `Could not connect to server: Operation timed out. Is the server running on host "80.XX.XXX.XXX" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` ... Do I need to open a port somewhere ?

Comment: I have no idea what your network setup might be, but if you are running a firewall of any kind, then you'll need to make sure port 5432 is open.